# Resize HTML canvas with respect to inner content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I am currently making an [esoteric language](http://razetime.github.io/limn) which requires a theoretically infinite canvas. Basically, it should be able to resize and fit the contents of the drawing in and outside it's existing boundaries.

[image: Black Squiggle, Red outline rectangle and brown solid rectangle]

The brown region indicates the original canvas boundaries. The black lines are the drawing, and the red boundary is what it should expand to.

When I tried searching about this, all I got was things relating to using the `<canvas>` tag in a responsive layout.

How do I achieve this effect using the HTML `<canvas>` element?

Comment: Some code of what you tried would be nice ... canvas have width & height you can increase that to suit your needs

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Ok, I willa dd some code today. Changing width and height isn't enough. I also need to translate the contents of the drawing to the visible area.